# Isabelle/Simpl new heap image does not show in jEdit

Tags: linux, isabelle, jedit

I have recently started using Isabelle/jEdit.  I have created a heap image for the Simpl AFP entry.  I made use of command line `isabelle build` tool to create the new image.  I can see and use the image with ProofGeneral and [Isabelle/Eclipse](http://andrius.velykis.lt/2013/04/isabelle-eclipse-released).  Unfortunately, I cannot see it via jEdit.

If use:

```
isabelle jedit -d isabelle_afp/Simpl -l Simpl
```

I can see Simpl but I believe it just rebuilds a Simpl image on the fly.

Any ideas?

Here's the heap located in the expected place:

```
~ > ls -l .isabelle/Isabelle2013-2/heaps/polyml-5.5.1_x86_64-linux/
total 425424
-r--r--r-- 1 george users 435622904 Feb 24 11:32 Simpl
drwxr-xr-x 2 george users      4096 Feb 24 11:32 log
```

Here's what my system looks like:

```
~ > uname -a 
Linux athina 3.11.1 #4 SMP Wed Jan 22 16:45:25 EST 2014 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In your `isabelle jedit -d isabelle_afp/Simpl -l Simpl` the heap image will only be built on the fly if it does not already exist. Thus, after the first time of calling the above command line you should be fine. For the rest, you said you built a heap image via `isabelle build`. Could you give the exact command line you used?

Comment: `isabelle build -b -D isabelle_afp/Simpl`

Comment: I did removed the heap image and rebuild it with `isabelle jedit -d isabelle_afp/Simpl -l Simpl`.  I know see the building taking place.  Unfortunately, I still do not see Simpl in the sessions pulldown menu.  I am not sure it matters, I invoked isabelle `Isabelle2013-2/Isabelle2013-2` and `Isabelle2013-2/bin/isabelle jedit`.

Comment: Did you register the AFP as Isabelle component in your `~/.isabelle/Isabelle2013-2/etc/settings`? (Via `init_component "/full/path/to/afp/dir"`)

Comment: hm, nope I did not register any such component.  I just did a find on init_component and I do not see it anywhere on my system.  Can you provide me with more info please?

Answer (score 2):

See http://afp.sourceforge.net/using.shtml for how to register the AFP as a component in Isabelle.

This tells Isabelle where the AFP ROOT session files are. You can think of it as adding the AFP to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

In the user‑home of Isabelle (not the home of the Isabelle system itself), which is `~/.isabelle` on UNIX‑likes (don't know for Windows), you may create a `ROOTS` file if it does not already exists. Then in `ROOTS` adds an `$AFP` line (literally, don't expand the variable) if there is not already such a line. If the `Simpl` theory still does not show up in jEdit's Isabelle theories list, this may be that the AFP was not setted up correctly. If so, check, the file `~/.isabelle/etc/components` and see if the file contains a line for the location you choose for your local copy of the AFP.